# create.blade.php is showing 404| Not Found

Tags: php, laravel-7

community!

I was learning laravel framework and got stuck at resource controller concept

I made a resource controller with the help of artisan command i.e php artisan make:controller PostController --resource

Here’s  the code:
create.blade.php(which is views/posts folder)

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-mid-8 col-md-offset-2" >
    <h1>Create New Post</h1>
    <hr>
   
    <form action="posts/create" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                  name="title" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                  name="body" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
</div>
</div>
    @endsection
```

PostController.php

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    

    
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }
```

web.php (route)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

please, guide me what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Add method name in web.php like this, `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController@create');`

Comment: Or try changing method name from `create()` to `index()` in PostController.php

Comment: can you paste your url too during create ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('posts/create', 'PostController@create')->name('posts');
```

> And change your .blde form action and method

```
action="{{route('posts')}}"  method="post"
```

> Also change your controller method

```
public function create(Request $r){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow design guides on the official laravel website.
When you write

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

it creates specific routes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers) documentation. 
In your case you want to display that route

```
GET /posts/create   create  posts.create
```

So it means that this route is looking to `create` function. Your code seems fine but `404` means that your create method can not find specified blade. Please check where you put it and url that you use to access is `http:yourUrl/posts/create`. 
Also form data usually passed (good design pattern) by POST method and i suggest not to hardcode route name that will help you maintain your code easier:

```
<form action="{{route("here route_name for post method")}}" method="POST">
```